# Check for references in other solutions - Rider

Tags: c#, rider

I've got a solution (let's call it A) with a project in it that throws out a nuget package.

This nuget package is consumed in a bunch of projects that are in a different solution (let's call it B).

Is there an easy way for me to get Rider to check for references in B whilst I'm working with A?

I'm trying to check what methods in A are used where to see if I can easily rip some stuff out. Unfortunately, I can't easily just do a find on the method names because there's a lot of overloading and I only care about some versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emails with Jetbrains Customer Support indicate this is currently not possible:

> If you're referring to a case where you would have a single instance
> of Rider open and you'd be able to search for usages of symbols in
> another solution - regrettably, it's not possible at the moment. We
> have a feature request to allow having multiple solutions open in a
> single "project": RIDER-10495 Having multiple solutions in a project.
> Implementing this request would allow searching usages across multiple
> solutions. Feel free to upvote this request and click Watch to
> subscribe to status updates.   For the time being, I can suggest the
> following steps to find usages of a specific signature of an
> overloaded method:
>
> ```
> Open the solution that uses the NuGet package
> Navigate to the corresponding assembly in the solution
> Locate the method with the required signature in the decompiled code
> Invoke Find Usages on the method
> ```
>
> Please see the attached screenshot for reference.    Let me know if
> you have any other questions. Have a great day!

However, there is an [open feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-10495).